# performance impact ->modifying an object in Observable Collection vs Removing and adding a new object?

Tags: c#, performance

I have an observable collection of a particular type T. Now I have a listener set to third party service and I am getting an object T which is actually a modification to an existing object in that observable collection.

What should I do?

1>Find the object that has been modified and then one by one change all the properties to the newly obtained value

OR

2>just delete the object from the list and add the obtained object

Note:
I can find the object from the collection by LINQ query using an Id property of class T and it is unique for each object. The question is after I find the object will I remove it and add the new one which has the same ID, or do I modify the existing one?

Comment: Can I suggest 3>profile?

Comment: I would, for the sake of readability, just replace the item in the collection with the new on. But you can always do some testing on your own to figure out which is faster.

Comment: @BlackBear I am curious, how would one do that? Will be a good new thing to learn.

Comment: BlackBear what do you mean by 3>profile?

Comment: He means test your scenarios to see how they actually perform as opposed to guessing.

Comment: @Abhinav with a profiler (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming), visual studio ultimate comes with a nice one, I don't know about the other versions). It tells you which are the slowest parts along with many other interesting statistics about your code

Comment: @BlackBear I know what profiling is, thx tho :). Btw I thought `profile` is some sort of library like `AutoMap` etc that just updates the existing object instance with a newer object instance wherever changes found.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution will be the fastest.

Adding and removing an object from an `ObservableCollection` is pretty slow. The remove-and-add operation will raise 2 `CollectionChanged` events.

The problem with the first solution can be the searching.
You can use a more sophisticated search algorithm or you can use a dictionary to keep your items indexed by id.

For example:

```
class ComplexObj //Maybe should implement INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string SomeProperty{get;set;}
}

Dictionary<int, ComplexObj> lookup = new Dictionary<int, ComplexObj>();
ObservableCollection<ComplexObj> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<ComplexObj>();
```

When you add an item to the collection make sure to add it in the dictionary too:

```
public void AddNewObj(ComplexObj obj)
{
    lookup.Add(obj.Id, obj);
    myCollection.Add(obj);
}
```

Then when you need to update a specific object:

```
public void Update(ComplexObj obj)
{
     lookup[obj.Id].SomeProperty = obj.SomeProperty;
}
```

Comment: By the way there are about 10 properties in complexObj and each has a notify event fired too :(

Comment: Something to bear in mind also is that I'm presuming you have a UI template bound to these objects. It is likely faster to change the values than to remove the object from the collection (which will likely remove elements from the visual tree) and add another (creating elements). It might be that your control is virtualising so hence why the real answer (as already suggested) is to profile.

Comment: @Debdeep You should fire the PropertyChanged event only if really the property has changed. If you don't, you are implementing the pattern in the wrong way.

Comment: but if 10 out of 10 properties change then it will fire for each, and at least 2 to 3 will change in real life usage of the application.

Comment: @Debdeep nothing prevents you from providing a method that does updates in bulk by accessing the backing fields instead of the properties. That way you can avoid the per property notification.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I need to show the update  on UI too. So can you please show a piece of code where there is example of update on backing fields and then finally notification sent to UI to refresh the whole row in UI?

Comment: @Debdeep please see my answer and let me know if that's useful.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in request to comment by OP.

You could implement a class, that supports bulk updates. To do that you need to provide method(s) that set the necessary values by accessing the underlying fields directly instead of going through the properties. Once all the values are set, you trigger notification for the entire object. Here's a simple class to illustrate the idea:

```
class BindableTypeThatSupportsBulkUpdate : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _Text1;
    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _Text1; }
        set { _Text1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string _Text2;
    public string Text2
    {
        get { return _Text2; }
        set { _Text2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public void BulkUpdate(string t1, string t2)
    {
        _Text1 = t1;
        _Text2 = t2;

        // Passing String.Empty as the name causes notification to fire for all the     properties
        NotifyPropertyChanged(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

This is simplified, but you probably get the idea anyway.

The `BulkUpdate` method sets two fields and then triggers notification on the entire object. I.e. you'll only get a single update even if you update multiple values.

Comment: It satisfies most conditions of my requirement. Just one question, will the Notification be fired one by one for all the properties? If yes then the UI will get a separate message in the message pump for each property, and will this be faster or will it be better to remove the whole row from UI and Add a new one?

Comment: No there's only one notification triggered by raising notification using the empty string. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh758320 under Change notification.

Comment: I think I am asking a very stupid question, but as per my understanding binding works as a mediator and each Dependency Property on UI has a separate binding object which binds to each property on Model. Now if there is some kind of code created by Microsoft to update all the Dependency Properties, how will it work internally? It will need to walk through all the binding objects and call a function to update its value right? If yes then indirectly again we are calling notifypropertychanged for each property?

Comment: Notification of changes is implemented using regular events. By default there's an event fired per property. To avoid doing this, you can use the approach tbove and raise the event passing the magic value of `String.Empty` in WinRT (null in WPF/Silverlight) to inform the binding that the entire object needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Lets assume a DataGrid with 10 columns and binds to observable collection where each object of collection has notifypropertchanged. Finally UI needs to be updated after a modification of private fields of an object in the collection and it will be done binding by binding, or is there some other sort of magic? I might be missing out and not so knowledgeable, please enlighten me on how this entire object update will work internally.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation but I would assume that binding in that case would have to enumerate the bound properties and get the value for each of those.

Comment: Exactly!!! and this would give the same performance as updating the properties directly :) .. so updating fields privately is same as the solution by Alberto ..

Comment: As for the performance, you should measure this. Guessing performance is futile. I don't believe the behavior would be the same though, because you're replacing a number of invocations by a single invocation + some sort of enumeration.

Comment: I believe the performance would be the same. In a simple explanation you have to call 5 functions which you can call one by one inside main method. However your solution is to create another wrapper function inside which you are calling the five functions, and then calling the wrapper function inside your main method :) .. In short the total number of steps stays same. But thanks for your time!!

Comment: I don't believe there's a function wrapping the same number of invocation, but instead of guess why don't you take a look at the implementation.

Comment: Logically that's what it is .. however always there can be magic. Do let me know if you find any article or proof otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Updates(Thanks to @Alberto and @BlackBear for giving me directions):

I tested with XamGrid and observable collection of class T which has 10 properties binding to grid.
Each property raises a notification only if its value changes. Also used dictionary approach of @Alberto.

Deleting and Addding approach takes about 3x to 4x time where as Modification Approach takes x time. However this holds good when your actual object and modified object has only difference in 2 to 3 properties(that means not all properties of actual object are different from the properties of modified object, just 2 properties are different, so raising just two notifications for property change.)

If your modified object has about 5 or 6 properties raising the notification then the performance of modification becomes same as removing and adding a row.

So bottom line is more the difference between actual and modified object more the time taken to modify it, and at a point of time you may think of dropping the actual object and adding the modified object.

For me standard modified object has a difference of 2 to 3 properties from the actual object and performance will be better for Modification of existing object.